# react native cant display data from SQLite storage (local database)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-sqlite

i'm used `react-native-SQLite-storage` package in my project .. and i follow all steps in documentation .. and i create new database in this path `/android/app/src/main/assets/appointment_db.db` and i call the package in some page and i tried `console.log` it give me that the

> OPEN database: appointment_db.db

but query not executed.
this is my code

```
 getDB = () =>{

        var db = SQLite.openDatabase("appointment_db.db", "1.0", "Test Database", 200000);
        try{

       db.transaction((tx)=>{

  var  x =  tx.executeSql('select * from users where id = 1',(tx,results) => {

            var len = results.rows.length;

            console.log(x);


          });

        });}
        catch(error){
          alert(error);
        }

      }
```

Comment: How are you saying query is not executed? BTW you doing console.log(x) which doesn't exist in your code

Comment: i edit my question